# Comparing custom Fractions

Tags: python

I'm working through a [book](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/index.html) now and I have a question regarding one of [exercises](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Introduction/ProgrammingExercises.html) (#6).
So we have a hand-made `Fraction` class and, besides all other kinds of things, we want to compare two fractions.

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, num, den):
        if not (isinstance(num, int) and isinstance(den, int)):
            raise ValueError('Got non-int argument')
        if den == 0:
            raise ValueError('Got 0 denominator')
        self.num = num
        self.den = den

    # some class methods 

    def __lt__(self, other):
        selfnum = self.num * other.den
        othernum = other.num * self.den
        return selfnum < othernum

    # some class methods

# trying it out
x = Fraction(1, -2)
y = Fraction(1, 3)
```

However, when we evaluate `x < y`, the result is `False`. I thought of making new attribute to store sign, but that messes everything up quite a bit.

Due to lack of better alternative, I added `if` in the method, and here's what I got

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    selfnum = self.num * other.den
    othernum = other.num * self.den
    if self.den * other.den > 0:
        return selfnum < othernum
    else:
        return selfnum > othernum
```

Although it seems to be working, I wonder, if there is more elegant solution.

**Update**
Storing sign in numerator does what I wanted (I can just change 2 lines instead of adding a conditional in each method).

Comment: Your alternative, with `if`, is never going to work. You stored `abs(den)` in `__init__`, so `self.den * other.den` is **always** going to be greater than 0.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I overlooked it, thanks. In my code I don't have use `abs` and it seems to be working.

Comment: At which point the *original* `__lt__` version you created works just  fine too.

Comment: My suggestion: ensure that `.den` is always positive.

Comment: @PM2Ring; Why? what if the numerator is also negative? Why use `abs()` *at all*?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters the original version didn't work. Let's take and example from the code using `x` and `y`. 1*3 > 1*(-2), so `__lt__` outputs `False`

Comment: @Basil: you confused `x` and `y`. `x` is `Fraction(1, -2)`, so `x < y` is `(1 * -2) < (1 * 3)` is `True`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: My suggestion is to initialize the denominator as a positive integer and store the sign of the fraction in the numerator. So if both the `num` and `den` args of `__init__` are negative then both `self.num` and `self.den` are positive. And any of the `Fraction` methods need to ensure that `.den` stays positive, but that's easy to do, IME.

Comment: @Basil: it looks to me that you are producing plenty of confusion for yourself by using different versions of `__init__` that you didn't share with us in your question; you stated *In my code I don't have use `abs` and it seems to be working*. Sort out your versions, then test again, paying attention to wether or not you are using `abs()`. Using `abs()` is the *core* of your problem however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume that both denominators are positive, you can safely do the comparison (since `a/b < c/d` would imply `ad < bc`). I would just store the sign in the numerator:

```
self.num = abs(num) * (1 if num / den > 0 else -1)
self.den = abs(den)
```

Or:

```
self.num = num
self.den = den

if self.den < 0:
    self.num = -self.num
    self.den = -self.den
```

And your `__lt__` method can be:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.num * other.den < other.num * self.den
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters: OP handled it implicitly with `if self.den * other.den > 0`, since `a/b < c/d` implies `ad < bc` if the signs of `b` and `d` are the same. It's just not very elegant.

Comment: @PM2Ring: and there we have the bug in *my* assumptions. I swapped denominators between the fractions being compared.